# Copy Multiple Charts from Sheets to Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have switched from Microsoft to Google Workspace.

We have a Sheet with multiple tabs with a table and graph in each tab. I would like to automate inserting these graphs (as images) at specific points into a preformated Google Doc. I am sure this is something very routinely done.

I am told this can be done with Google Apps Script, but I have never used it.

Could someone point me to some good examples to get me started?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Here is a sample example script to get a chart from Google Sheet and place in a Google Doc.  I use as a place holder the paragraph "Chart1".

**Spreadsheet**

[image]

**Doc (Before)**

[image]

**Doc (After)**

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function testChart() {
  try {
    let charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Chart").getCharts();
    // In this case there is only 1
    let chart = charts[0];
    chart = chart.getAs("image/png");
    let doc = DocumentApp.openById("1A........................ds");
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let paras = body.getParagraphs();
    for( let i=0; i<paras.length; i++ ) {
      let para = paras[i];
      let text = para.getText();
      if( text === "Chart1" ) {
        para.addPositionedImage(chart);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Sheet.getCharts()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCharts())
- [DocumentApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openById(String))
- [Document.getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getBody())
- [PositionImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image)

Comment: Thanks for the script, but I am not even sure where to start with it. I need more of a "How To" manual.

Comment: Do you know how to create a script in Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, but what I do not know is:
1. How to select the Google Doc
2. How to select the tab where the table is
3. How to select where to place it in the Doc file
4 And repeats that for 25 tabs

Comment: Look at the references I provided. get the Id of the Google Doc and then use `openById` as shown.  Within the doc you need some placeholder to tell where to put the graph as I show above.  You did not mention tables, just graphs.

Comment: You can do it from either side.  Open Google Spreadsheet and place in a Doc.  Or open a Google Doc and `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` to get the chart.   If you were in the Doc and there is only one chart you could use the cursor location to place the chart.